# SetPerTcpConnectionEStats fails and can't get GetPerTcpConnectionEStats multiple times c++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp

I am following the example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getpertcp6connectionestats?redirectedfrom=MSDN to get the TCP statistics. Although, I got it working and get the statistics in the first place, still I want to record them every a time interval (which I haven't managed to do so), and I have the following questions.

1. The SetPerTcpConnectionEStats () fails with status != NO_ERROR and equal to 5. Although, it fails, I can get the statistics. Why?
2. I want to get the statistics every, let's say 1 second. I have tried two different ways; a) to use a while loop and use a std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s), where I could get the statistics every ~1sec, but the whole app was stalling (is it because of the this), I supposed that I am blocking the operation of the main, and b) (since *a)* failed) I tried to call TcpStatistics() from another function (in different class) that is triggered every 1 sec (I store clientConnectRow to a global var). However, in that case (b), GetPerTcpConnectionEStats() fails with winStatus = 1214 (ERROR_INVALID_NETNAME) and of course TcpStatistics() cannot get any of the statistics.

a)

```
ClassB::ClassB()
{
   UINT winStatus = GetTcpRow(localPort, hostPort, MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB, (PMIB_TCPROW)clientConnectRow);  
   ToggleAllEstats(clientConnectRow, TRUE);
   thread t1(&ClassB::TcpStatistics, this, clientConnectRow); 
   t1.join();
}

ClassB::TcpStatistics()
{
   while (true)
  {
     GetAndOutputEstats(row, TcpConnectionEstatsBandwidth)
     // some more code here
     this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(1000));
  }
}
```

b)

```
ClassB::ClassB()
{
    MIB_TCPROW client4ConnectRow;
    void* clientConnectRow = NULL;
    clientConnectRow = &client4ConnectRow;
    UINT winStatus = GetTcpRow(localPort, hostPort, MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB, (PMIB_TCPROW)clientConnectRow);    
    m_clientConnectRow = clientConnectRow;
    TcpStatistics();
}

ClassB::TcpStatistics()
{
  ToggleAllEstats(m_clientConnectRow , TRUE);
  void* row = m_clientConnectRow;
  GetAndOutputEstats(row, TcpConnectionEstatsBandwidth)
  // some more code here
}

ClassB::GetAndOutputEstats(void* row, TCP_ESTATS_TYPE type)
{
   //...
    winStatus = GetPerTcpConnectionEStats((PMIB_TCPROW)row, type, NULL, 0, 0, ros, 0, rosSize, rod, 0, rodSize);

    if (winStatus != NO_ERROR) {wprintf(L"\nGetPerTcpConnectionEStats %s failed. status = %d",  estatsTypeNames[type], winStatus); // 
    }
    else { ...}
}

ClassA::FunA()
{
  classB_ptr->TcpStatistics();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for the second part of my question. I am posting it here, in case someone else find it useful. There might be other solutions too, more advanced, but this is how I did it myself. We have to first Obtain MIB_TCPROW corresponding to the TCP connection and then to Enable Estats collection before dumping current stats. So, what I did was to add all of these in a function and call this instead, every time I want to get the stats.

```
void
ClassB::FunSetTcpStats()
{
    MIB_TCPROW client4ConnectRow;
    void* clientConnectRow = NULL;
    clientConnectRow = &client4ConnectRow;

    //this is for the statistics
    UINT winStatus = GetTcpRow(lPort, hPort, MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB, (PMIB_TCPROW)clientConnectRow); //lPort & hPort in htons!
    if (winStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        wprintf(L"\nGetTcpRow failed on the client established connection with %d", winStatus);
        return;
    }   
    //
    // Enable Estats collection and dump current stats.
    //
    ToggleAllEstats(clientConnectRow, TRUE);
    TcpStatistics(clientConnectRow); // same as GetAllEstats() in msdn
}
```